# Advise on orm modelling in django

Tags: django, orm

I am building a webapp in which users place orders with nested information. I am after some advice on best practice so I can do some more research.

The idea is that a user either loads an existing order, or creates a new order. They then fill in the subsequent order fields, which can be on a one to many basis. My initial thought was to use a variable for order_id and use a foreign key to link the instances of the other classes. However, this seems overcomplicated. order_id would have to be unique and sequential. Is this the best approach to this issue?

```
class Order(models.Model):
    order_id= xxxx
    created_by = xxxx

class A(models.Model):
    order_id = models.ForeignKey(xxxxx)
    someclassafield = xxxx

class B(models.Model):
    order_id = models.ForeignKey(xxxxx)
    someclassbfield = xxxx
```

This would give the user the ability to create orders such as below:

```
Order 1
(Class_A, order_id, someclassafield)
(Class_A, order_id, someclassafield)
(Class_A, order_id, someclassafield)
(Class_B, order_id, someclassbfield)

Order 2
(Class_A, order_id, someclassafield)
(Class_A, order_id, someclassafield)
(Class_B, order_id, someclassbfield)
(Class_B, order_id, someclassbfield)
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question in case this is of any use to others. From research what I actually want is a one to many relationship.
Source:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

```
from django.db import models

class Reporter(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['headline']
```